# binary tree add left and add right nodes not adding

Tags: python, algorithm, tree, binary-tree

I'm reading the following data as part of an assignment into a **binary tree** (not a **strict binary search tree**):

```
5
4 1 2
2 3 4
5 -1 -1
1 -1 -1
3 -1 -1
```

They're being read into three lists in python `self.key`, `self.left` and `self.right` where the first line has the integer `n` is the number of nodes. The next n lines are key, left, right. Where left is the key of the left child of the parent is `key[left]` and likewise the key of the right child is `key[right]`, so for example the first line is the key of 4 is the root and `key[1]` meaning 2 is the left child of 4 and `key[2]` meaning 5 is the right child of 4 and so on and -1 for left and right means this key is a leaf:

[Tree structure for this example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5nTYl.jpg)

The problem is the left and right children of the root are being added but none of the children of these are being added. Am I correctly adding nodes to the tree? I cannot just add them based on value of the key because it's not a **strict binary search tree** as some other examples make clear, such as *root = 0* and *left child = 70* and *right child = 20*. The output of inOrder traversal is `2 4 5` (should be `1 2 3 4 5`) which leads me to believe I'm not adding the further nodes. Any help on the adding methods would be appreciated...

```
import sys, threading
sys.setrecursionlimit(10**6) # max depth of recursion
threading.stack_size(2**27)  # new thread will get stack of such size


class Node:
    def __init__(self, val):
        self.l = None
        self.r = None
        self.v = val

class Tree:
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = None

    def getRoot(self):
        return self.root

    def add_root(self, val):
        if(self.root is None):
            self.root = Node(val)

    def add_left(self, val, node):
        if(node.l is None):
            node.l = Node(val)

    def add_right(self, val, node):
        if(node.r is None):
            node.r = Node(val)

    def deleteTree(self):
        # garbage collector will do this for us. 
        self.root = None


    def inOrder(self):
        self.result = []
        if(self.root is not None):
            self._inOrder(self.root, self.result)
            return self.result
        else:
            print('root is None')

    def _inOrder(self, node, result):
        if(node != None):
            self._inOrder(node.l, self.result)
            self.result.append(node.v)
            self._inOrder(node.r, self.result)

    def read(self):
        self.n = int(sys.stdin.readline())
        self.key = [0 for i in range(self.n)]
        self.left = [0 for i in range(self.n)]
        self.right = [0 for i in range(self.n)]
        for i in range(self.n):
            [a, b, c] = map(int, sys.stdin.readline().split())
            self.key[i] = a
            self.left[i] = b
            self.right[i] = c

        #adding root
        self.add_root(self.key[0])
        if self.left[0] != -1: 
            #add left of root
            self.add_left(self.key[self.left[0]], self.root)
        if self.right[0] != -1:
            #add right of root
            self.add_right(self.key[self.right[0]], self.root)

        #where it is not adding left and right nodes
        for i in range(1, self.n):
            if self.left[i] != -1:
                # adding the other left nodes
                self.add_left(self.key[self.left[i]], Node(self.key[i]))
            if self.right[i] != -1:
                # adding the other right nodes
                self.add_right(self.key[self.right[i]], Node(self.key[i]))

def main():
    tree = Tree()
    tree.read()
    print(" ".join(str(x) for x in tree.inOrder()))
    #print(" ".join(str(x) for x in tree.preOrder()))
    #print(" ".join(str(x) for x in tree.postOrder()))

threading.Thread(target=main).start()
```

Comment: The binary tree in your example doesn't seem valid. Node 4 has node 2 as its right child, but node 2 has node 4 also as its right child. In the picture node 4 has 2 and 5 as its children, not 1 and 2. In addition, you initialize some lists to be length "n" but you start numbering your nodes from 1, which will cause index out of bounds exception when you try to process node with id "n". Perhaps try fixing these first?

Comment: The first line after n gives the root node key in the first position then left and right children as key[i] and key[i] so the root is key[0], then 2 is key[1] which is the root's left child and 5 is key[2] as the root's right child. So the first column in the data are key list values starting at the root at key[0]. The second column is left as key[number] and the third column is right as key[number] giving the left and right children of the key in the first column, unless left or right are -1 indicating no child. So node with key 2 has left child 1 and right child 3 because of indices 3 and 4.

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood the format. In that case your problem seems to be in read() function: you're always creating a new node when calling add_left and add_right in the latter loop, but the nodes aren't stored anywhere. You're not accessing the existing objects that you already have, but you're creating a new object and throwing it away.

Comment: Oh. How would I go about accessing the previous nodes?

Comment: You can store them into a list or dictionary, and instead of calling Node's constructor when calling add_left/right, you just give the existing node from the list/dictionary.

Comment: Thanks I'll give that a shot.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks I got it to work - I added the nodes `Node(key[i])` to a dictionary and `self.nodes[val] = [node, node.l, node.r]` and when adding the left and recursively searched the dictionary for inOrder, preOrder and postOrder tree traversals.

```
 class Node:
    def __init__(self, val):
        self.l = None
        self.r = None
        self.v = val

class Tree:

    def __init__(self):
        self.root = None
        self.nodes = {}

    def getRoot(self):
        return self.root

    def add_root(self, val):
        if(self.root is None):
            self.root = Node(val)
            self.nodes[val] = [self.root,-1,-1]

    def add_left(self, val, node):
        if(node.l is None):
            node.l = Node(val)
            self.nodes[node.v][1] = node.l

    def add_right(self, val, node):
        if(node.r is None):
            node.r = Node(val)
            self.nodes[node.v][2] = node.r

    def inOrder(self):
        self.result = []
        if(self.root is not None):
            self._inOrder(self.root, self.result)
            return self.result
        else:
            print('root is None')

    def _inOrder(self, node, result):
        if(node is not None):
            try:
                self._inOrder(self.nodes[node.v][1], self.result)
            except (IndexError, AttributeError):
                pass
            self.result.append(node.v)
            try:
                self._inOrder(self.nodes[node.v][2], self.result)
            except (IndexError, AttributeError):
                pass
    def preOrder(self):
        self.result = []
        if(self.root is not None):
            self._preOrder(self.root, self.result)
            return self.result
        else:
            print('root is None')

    def _preOrder(self, node, result):
        if(node is not None):
            self.result.append(node.v)
            try:
                self._preOrder(self.nodes[node.v][1], self.result)
            except (IndexError, AttributeError):
                pass
            try:
                self._preOrder(self.nodes[node.v][2], self.result)
            except (IndexError, AttributeError):
                pass

    def postOrder(self):
        self.result = []
        if(self.root is not None):
            self._postOrder(self.root, self.result)
            return self.result
        else:
            print('root is None')

    def _postOrder(self, node, result):
        if(node is not None):
            try:
                self._postOrder(self.nodes[node.v][1], self.result)
            except (IndexError, AttributeError):
                pass
            try:
                self._postOrder(self.nodes[node.v][2], self.result)
            except (IndexError, AttributeError):
                pass
            self.result.append(node.v)

    def read(self):
        self.n = int(sys.stdin.readline())
        self.key = [0 for i in range(self.n)]
        self.left = [0 for i in range(self.n)]
        self.right = [0 for i in range(self.n)]
        for i in range(self.n):
            [a, b, c] = map(int, sys.stdin.readline().split())
            self.key[i] = a
            self.left[i] = b
            self.right[i] = c

        #adding root
        self.add_root(self.key[0])

        for i in range(1, self.n):
            self.nodes[self.key[i]] = [Node(self.key[i]),-1,-1]

        for i in range(0, self.n):
            if self.left[i] != -1:
                # adding the other left nodes
                self.add_left(self.key[self.left[i]], self.nodes[self.key[i]][0])

            if self.right[i] != -1:
                # adding the other right nodes
                self.add_right(self.key[self.right[i]], self.nodes[self.key[i]][0])
```